# How can I create language pack for magento 2

Tags: magento2, store-view, language

**I am trying to create language pack for Norway,**

but I do not know how to create this .

I am unable to find any Magento extension for Norwegian language .

Please help me.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/270)?

Comment: no , thanks for this link@ i have one question. If  In my magneto  admin option already Norwegian language have then again need to create language pack.please help me

Comment: From my understanding, @SanjayYadav you need to create new Norwegian language pack.

Comment: see here https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow step to set different Language store for website :

**Step 1:**  Create different store view for a website like : English/German/Franch

**Step 2:** Download Language pack from any preferred source as [https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-norwegian-bokmal-norway-language-pack.html](https://github.com/splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE)

**Step 3:** Create `i18n` directory in **app** and place language pack into that directory with vendor name as well as package name

**Step 4:** Apply following commands

- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy <language_code>` ex. **nb_NO**

**Step 5:** `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Your language store is  ready now. Enjoy !

Comment: I did all thing but my module is not showing in  component manager http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1993556/4206301b97c1f3c43c18b12fe59946d2

Comment: which module you have created?

Comment: I have created i189 directory with no_NO.csv file , also pate a language directory  in vendor/magneto directory

Comment: create `i18n` directory and put your package with vendor name which you can find from registeration.php of the package

Comment: you mean all file of language

Comment: yes, need to put all file of that language pack

Comment: well, I am doing , app/i189/language-no_no/ it's good or not

Comment: its wrong, you have to create `i18n` and then package vendor name

Comment: package vendore name mean no_NO

Comment: Ronak Chauhan@ My code is working but my i18n folder is  in my theme directory.  but some content is changing and some not changing, like go to checkout does not change, so it's necessary to put  i18n folder to magento each particular folder , like , web , magento catalog , etc

Answer (score 1):

Translation has many ways, To translate by creating a new module is below:
Example: my pool code is: "`Tohq`", and my module is "`Norwegian`" 
1) create all necessary files for a new module: `Tohq/Norwegian/etc/module.xml`, `Tohq/Norwegian/registration.php`. 
2) And then, create `Tohq/Norwegian/i18n/nb_NO.csv` file. You input content to translate here.

I hope it help you!

Comment: I did all thing but my module is not showing in  component manager http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1993556/4206301b97c1f3c43c18b12fe59946d2

Comment: well let me know how  can i pool this code from git