# How can I add New language in magento 2 admin panel Locale Options?

Tags: magento2, language, language-package

I want to create Kurdish (ku_IQ) language site  magento 2.2.3 but

> Configuration==>Store View:  Kurdish ==> General==>Locale Options==> Kurdish  not found !!

Now i want to add Kurdish (ku_IQ) Locale Options ..

I create below file & Flush cache but nothing change on local new language

=> **`app/i18n/matinict/ku_iq/registration.php`**

=> **`app/i18n/matinict/ku_iq/language.xml`**

=> **`app/i18n/matinict/ku_iq/composer.json`**

=> **`app/i18n/matinict/ku_iq/ku_IQ.csv`**

Github:
https://github.com/matinict/magento-2-kurdish-language-pack

That not working.

How can add new Admin Locale Options language in magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

@matinict, I think currently **Kurdish** language pack isn't available for Magento 1 OR 2 versions.

You need to create your own language pack.

Here are some good tutorials for that.

[Check here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/270) OR [Magento Stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151804/how-can-i-create-language-pack-for-magento-2)

Hope it will help you !!

Comment: Great help for me , i am try now

Comment: Accept answer and giving upvote if it helps you.

Comment: still not come new language

Comment: Remove pub/static/* and var/* , Than execute upgrade and deploy command from Magento root.

Comment: deploy static clean var   but no luck

Comment: Compare your created language pack with default Magento's language pack and check if you missed something which is important.

Answer (score 1):

At last I solved the problem (in the worst way), maybe someone might need it:

```
/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Source/Locale.php

 
public function toOptionArray()
    {
         //return $this->_localeLists->getOptionLocales();
        $localeLists=$this->_localeLists->getOptionLocales();
        $localeLists[] = ['value'=>'kb_IQ', 'label'=>"Kurdish Bahdini (Iraq)"];
        $localeLists[] = ['value'=>'ks_IQ', 'label'=>"Kurdish Sorani (Iraq)"];
        return $localeLists;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps.

1. Add your language pack under following location with case sensitive directory name app/i18n/Magento/ku_IQ  (here IQ is in capital letter)
2. After that run following command

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

if you are using M 2.2 and above then use force for deploy like below

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f ku_IQ

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                     
  ku_IQ argument has invalid value, please run info:language:list for list of available locales

Comment: Hi,

I have analyzed and found this Language Pack is Still In developing.

Please look message on GIThub.

https://github.com/matinict/magento-2-kurdish-language-pack
** Still In developing may not enough helpfull for you. Magento 2 Kurdish (Iraqi Kurdistan) language